# Connect to instagram API via php

Tags: php, api, instagram

How to connect to instagram api using php to authenticate a user when I came to the server his data? Thanks in advance

Comment: We'd need a little more to work with. Do you have something started that doesn't work the way you think it should?

Comment: I have read the documentation, but did not understand anything)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need registrate your app:
http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/

Next in php handler:

```
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
$access_token_parameters = array(
    'client_id'                =>     '%client_id%',
    'client_secret'            =>     '%client_secret%',
    'grant_type'               =>     'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri'             =>     'http://domain.com/index.php',
    'code'                     =>     $code
);
$curl = curl_init($url);    // we init curl by passing the url
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true);   // to send a POST request
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$access_token_parameters);   // indicate the data to send
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);   // to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   // to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
$result = curl_exec($curl);   // to perform the curl session
curl_close($curl);   // to close the curl session

$user_data = json_decode($result,true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what we need. Excuse me for my ignorance!